# How do i remove my sender hostname in mail header

Tags: php, email, smtp, swiftmailer

how do i change example.com to localhost in mail header. I am using ubuntu postfix server and swift mailer for sending mails.

```
Received: from localhost (example.com. [12.12..121])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTP id s22si1128306qge.14.2016.04.06.00.17.45
    for <............@gmail.com>;
    Wed, 06 Apr 2016 00:17:45 -0700 (PDT)
```

Thanks

Comment: weird. Why do you want to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use directly the FQDN (exemple.com) of your mail sending host instead of "localhost" when specifying your `Swift_???Transport` either directly (Smtp), or via the command line arguments of you mail command (Sendmail).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "use", where/how do I set these values?